# Google autocomplete API returns places in my state first instead of the most "expected" places

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

I am using Google Autocomplete when entering addresses, this is the simple implementation:

```
autocomplete_origin_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('origin_address'), {types: ["geocode"]}
);
```

When I start typing "Lon", the first suggested place is `Long Beach, CA`, and the next one is "London United Kingdom" - that's just an example.

I am located in California. Generally said, when I start typing an address, the places that are offered to my are located in CA. How do I get offered the places in the whole North America?

I tried to modify my autocomplete setup, like:

```
autocomplete_origin_address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('origin_address'), {types: ["route", "geocode"]}
);
```

But in this case the autocomplete didn't offer anything (even when I kept in the array only `route`.

How to set up autocomplete to suggest the places not mainly from CA, but from the North America?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=> {
  $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" 
            + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude
            + "&sensor=false").then(data=> {
    for (let component of data.results[0].address_components) {
      if (component.types.includes("country")) {
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          $('#origin_address')[0], {types: ["geocode"],
          componentRestrictions: {country: component.short_name}}
        );
        break;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Firstly it gets current location using broswser's Geolocation API. Then it makes request to Google Maps API to get the country based on latitude and longitude. Then it initializes autocomplete, limiting it to this country.

See [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0yd947j/).